# ClassNotFoundException when using JDBC driver for DB2

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to connect to a DB2 database using JDBC. Therefore I downloaded the DB2 driver `db2jcc.jar` and added the path to the classpath while compiling and running my application (I'm not using an IDE). 
The following is the source of my Test-Application:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TestApp {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know, where my problem is?

Comment: You also need db2jcc_license_cu.jar.

Comment: Add the jars themselves to the classpath, not the directory with the jars.

Comment: That's, what I did ;)

Comment: How exactly do you start that programm?

Comment: 'java -cp "./db2jcc.jar;./db2jcc_license_cu.jar" TestApp'

Comment: So I guess the exception is about TestApp, not com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver, right?

Comment: yes, you're right. but why?

Comment: Always provide an snipped of the output. With the information provided we can only know that there a ClassNotFoundException, but there are too many classes, and we cannot provide a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling:

```
'javac -cp ".;(path)/db2jcc.jar;(path)/db2jcc_license_cu.jar" TestApp.java'
```

Then running

```
'java -cp ".;(path)/db2jcc.jar;(path)/db2jcc_license_cu.jar" TestApp'
```

You only need quotes if spaces in the file/path names also.

Comment: Make sure that the db2jcc.jar is in the same folder (or change the above so that it includes the folder as Edited) as your java files when compiling/running

Comment: In this case, the JAR files don't need to be on the compile time classpath.  (Though it doesn't do any harm ...)