# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while executing DB connection statements

Tags: java, exception, classnotfoundexception, java.lang.class

I have set of DB connection statements in my java file which takes the driver name, url, username and password from my property file and then try to make a connection. But I am keep getting error exactly in this try block . My code is

```
try {
    Class.forName(properties.getProperty("DB2.database.driver"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Unable to locate database driver:" + e);             
    return null;
}
```

The error message is

> Unable to locate database `driver:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

May i know why it is keep getting this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ClassNotFoundException when using JDBC driver for DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153477/classnotfoundexception-when-using-jdbc-driver-for-db2)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Include the *complete* stacktrace and error message.  As written, the problem could be a number of things,

Comment: @PetrAleksandrov . Thanks. your suggestion worked.

Comment: @StephenC The problem was because of missing DB2 jar. Thanks though.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash It worked after i added the required jar in classpath. Thanks.